# liquibase hsql db column creation error

Tags: java, hsqldb, liquibase

i am using hsql db and liquibase to create a db schema and the liquibase script am using is giving an error

```
<changeSet author="fryder" id="1492138266795-903">
        <createIndex indexName="ACCESS_GRP_IDX" tableName="ACCESS_GRP">
            <column computed="true" name="UPPER(&quot;DESCR&quot;)"/>
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>
```

cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'computed' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'. -> [Help 1]
plz help, note:- i created the schema defnition using liquibase generatechangelog method.

so for the people looking for answer.
HSQL db is not a fullfledged relational-db with all functions equal to oracle. removed UPPER(".. and the statement worked.

Comment: It means you cannot create an index on a computed function. With HSQLDB you need to create a GENERATED column based on the UPPER function. You can then create an index on this column.

Comment: yes, what i did is removed the index creation.but now it fails at liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: type not found or user lacks privilege: VARCHAR2 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR2(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Enable the Oracle syntax compatibility mode on HSQLDB. `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE`

Comment: hi fred,thank you for the quick response. However am already running with jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/sandboxdb;sql.syntax_ora=true

Comment: That doesn't work. Read the HSQLDB Guide chapter on Server.

Comment: my bad, it is working i had a liquibase-oracle extension in my class path.|
i am fighting with minValue is not allowed on hsqldb error now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141918/discussion-between-fryder-and-fredt).

Comment: Good luck with the rest of the issues.

Comment: thanks for the info fred,resolved all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with H2 ? it often has a more complete support of such features

Comment: i used with hsql itself..i combined it with Jmockit to mock some dbpackages.